# Excel doesn't multiply. All cells are in the right format

Tags: microsoft-excel

All cells are in correct format (either number or percentage) but the multiplication doesn't work. The file is also set to automatic calculation.

The cell where the formula is open shows 0, however the first column calculates perfectly:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you type those commas in?

Comment: press `Ctrl`+`grave accent (`). This will show all the formulas. Ensure all your formulas are right.  Remove all formatting and try `=1+1` and see if it works (say a simple formula)

Answer (score 0):

Try `=Product(I20,I25)`
If you have no result it means you have to remove the commas and use Number Format to write thousand separator